# @Test method is executed before @BeforeTest method is exited during multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, testng, selenium-java

I want to create some test data in @BeforeTest method in parallel with threads to save data creation time. Test data to be used later in @Test methods. As a sample I have added Thread.sleep() for now.
When I ran the test, once the threads are initiated and started on run() method, testNG executing @Test method even before all threads exiting run() method.
I want the @Test Method to be executed once all the threads are out of run() method and exited @BeforeTest method. TestNG version: 7.0.0.
Please help me solve this problem.

ThreadTest class

```
package mypackage;

public class ThreadTest implements Runnable{

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //lines to create some test data
    
    try {
        System.out.println("In thread run method");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("In thread out");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Test Class:

```
package mytestpackage;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import mypackage.*;

public class TestClass {

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {

         ThreadTest threadObj = new ThreadTest();
         
         executor.execute(threadObj);
    }
    
    executor.shutdown();
    
    System.out.println("Active thread count "+executor.getActiveCount());
    
}

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    
    System.out.println("In Test Method");
}

}
```

Sample Output:

```
   -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running mytestpackage.TestClass
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4f4a7090
In thread run method
In thread run method
In thread run method
In thread run method
In thread run method
Active thread count 5
In Test Method
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.648 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.083 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-04T20:49:11+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `executor.awaitTermination(..)` **after** you called `executor.shutdown();`. So that your current thread is blocked until all existing tasks are completed.

See the method description [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).